# Should I pass JSX through arguments or write many components?

Tags: reactjs

I've just started learning ReactJS and I came up with a (I think) simple problem. So I want to make this website, where user comes in and he sees one input field for email (above the input field there's some welcoming text etc.). He enters an email (there's some input validation for the field) and clicks next button, then the input field for password shows up (text above the input field changes, input validation is different etc.). After the user has entered the password and clicked next, at the next step maybe there're two inputs - one for birth date and other for choosing your gender etc.

My question is... what would be the best way to write this component(s) for every step? One approach I came up with, was I could write like 10 different components for every step and then have one "main" component that would push all of the other components into array. Then according to the step's number, I would display the right component from the array.

The other approach (if it's possible) would be to write one component and somehow pass HTML, validations and stuff like that through props. I am not sure if it's possible and if it is, would it be better. Could someone give me an advice? Thanks!

Here's some really basic code I wrote in a few minutes to  go back and forth between steps, but right here only the number of the step changes, everything else stays the same.

```
var Step = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Hello, I am step {this.props.stepNum}</div>
    );
  }
});

var Steps = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      currentStep: 0
    }
  },

  previousStep: function() {
    this.setState({
      currentStep: this.state.currentStep > 0 ? this.state.currentStep - 1 : 0
    })
  },

  nextStep: function() {
    this.setState({
      currentStep: this.state.currentStep < (this.props.totalSteps - 1) ? this.state.currentStep + 1 : (this.props.totalSteps - 1)
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    console.log(this.state.currentStep);
    var allSteps = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.props.totalSteps; i++) {
        allSteps.push(<Step stepNum={i} key={i} />);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {allSteps[this.state.currentStep]}
        <button onClick={this.previousStep}>Previous Step</button>
        <button onClick={this.nextStep}>Next Step</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Steps totalSteps={3} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to create a component for every step.

**Keep your components small.**

In this way, you would have every step in a separate component and it's easy for maintenance and you can use every step in a different places in your code.

[You can read this.](https://camjackson.net/post/9-things-every-reactjs-beginner-should-know)

[Look here what "facebook" says.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html)

> When designing interfaces, break down the common design elements (buttons, form fields, layout components, etc.) into reusable components with well-defined interfaces. That way, the next time you need to build some UI, you can write much less code. This means faster development time, fewer bugs, and fewer bytes down the wire.

Hope this helps.